# securing compromised account

Tags: support, security, password

I left my account logged in on a computer owned by someone else, they have decided to troll and so ive changed my password and cleared my session. I verified with SE openid that they did not log in after that, but they still have access to my chat account. How do I handle this situation, and can password change trigger an actual working global cookie invalidation in the future?

Comment: Nice music.  Reminiscent of Skrillex.

Comment: Heh thanks, my latest upload sucks though, glad you found something nice :)

Comment: Saw your flag.  Did you still need help on this issue?

Comment: im not sure, i asked to be suspended from chat until its sorted and i still am, not sure how to try going back and not sure if its really sorted or not

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you left multiple services logged in - your email (required to confirm a Stack Exchange OpenID password change), SE OpenID, SE sites, possibly others.

The best defense is, honestly, to never leave yourself logged in on someone else's computer. Incognito browser sessions come in very handy for this sort of thing.

Now that the damage has been done, I see that the offending credential has been removed from your profile, and your login sessions have been cleared. When you have your logins secured, let us know and we'll lift your (currently network-wide) suspension.

Comment: Just saw this post, and it made me smile when taken in context with our discussion about the log out link :) Thanks for your work as a moderator!

Comment: @Chris Thanks. :) There's also an extra gotcha here, since logging out on the sites doesn't (and can't) also log you out from whatever provider you're signed in with (including ours), which just adds another thing to consider to the whole "let's not encourage folks to log out" argument. :)

Comment: Definitely an SE OpenID flaw, it was the only provider ever attached to my account at the time of the issue. The Problem is that SE OpenID does not provide a global logout option, making each sites global logout a silly useless tool when combined with SE OpenID.